# Mollification of $L^{\infty}$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convolution

We know when $1\leq p<\infty$ , the mollification function $f^{\epsilon}=\phi_{\epsilon}*f$ for $L^{p}(R^n)$ functions converge to $f$ in $L^{p}$ norm, when $p=\infty$ it might be wrong. But who can disprove it or give a counterexample will help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take any $f\in L^\infty$ that is truly discontinuous (meaning, it can't be made continuous by redefining on a null set).

Comment: Or for a more concrete example, consider a step function in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f^\varepsilon$ will always be continuous, so a jump discontinuity anywhere will to the trick (the continuous approximation will *have to* deviate from $f$ by at least $\frac\delta2$ where $\delta$ is the magnitude of the jump) To become concrete, take $f = \chi_{[0,1]}$ the characteristic function of the unit interval.

Comment: AlexR, could you explain this a little bit more? I know from a few books on PDEs that this is true. On the other hand, in the area of numerical solving of PDEs, sometimes we get a smooth function  that converges to the shock wave (i.e discontinuous piecewise constant function - it looks like a step function basically). If we think of a smooth function as an approximation with a mollifier, i.e. $f^{\epsilon}$ and of a shock wave as a $L^{\infty}$ function $f$, it looks to me that $f^{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ in $L^{\infty}$. I have never understood this completely.

Comment: Note the $L^\infty$ norm is the supremum. By the intermediate value theorem any continuous function with values 0 and 1 will attain 0.5 somewhere. Therefor the supremum of the difference between a continuous approximation and the characteristic function will be at least 0.5, disproving convergence in $L^\infty$.

Comment: AlexR, thank you for the reply. Reminder of the intermediate value theorem and that the $L^{\infty}$ norm is the supremum was very helpful. I guess that in numerical solving of PDEs we do not need to pay attention this much on this type of questions (they just find approximation that is good enough). I guess the same story goes for the $L_{loc}^{\infty}$ space?

Comment: AlexR, I have an additional question (besides the one above about $L_{loc}^{\infty}$ question): Would it be the same answer if instead of $\mathbb{R}^N$ we use some subset of it? And thanks for the help.

Comment: Since the arguments only uses local continuity properties, localisation (to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$) or extension of the same argument to $L^\infty_{\rm loc}$ is unproblematic - just pick a compact set containing the discontinuity and convergence breaks as before.

Comment: AlexR, I have an additional question. I hope you will have time to answer. Let's say that I have a shock wave (i.e. discontinuous step function) $f$, then mollify it and get $f^{\epsilon}$, could I assume something like this: $f^{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ or in space of Radon measures or some other space? Based on your answer I know that we do not have convergence in the space $L^{\infty}$. This is connected to the problem I am currently working on. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think you should be able to prove convergence in all $L^p$ spaces with $p<\infty$.

Comment: AlexR, it took me a few days but I figured it out. If I have a step function (i.e. $L^{\infty}$ function) and molify it, I could show convergence in all $L^p$ spaces with $p<\infty$. And because $L^p$ spaces are the subsets of the space of Radon measures $\mathcal{M}$ and of the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}^{,}$, I could assume the concergence in both of them too. Thanks again for the help and sorry if I was asking the obviuos.