# Convergence with mollifiers

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm studyin Brezis' PDE with a property:
[image]

What about $p = \infty$?

I think that when $p = \infty$, the statement is wrong but I can't give an example.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: On $\mathbb R$ let $f$ be the characteristic function of $[0,\infty).$ Then $f$ is not the uniform limit on $\mathbb R$ of any sequence of continuous functions. Thus the sequence of continuous functions $\rho_n*f$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb R.$ Hence $\rho_n*f$ does not converge to $f$ in $L^\infty.$

Comment: @Michele: I very much doubt that $\varrho_n \ast f $ has compact support.

Comment: @PhoemueX: You are completely right. I deleted my upper comment.

Comment: similar post  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960512/mollification-of-l-infty-functions